# redhat cycle through workspace switcher

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

This is redhat enterprise. I can't seem to install wmctrl (sudo yum search can't find it; about to get all source dependencies to compile).

I can go from 1->2->3 and 3->2->1, but I'd like to be able to go 1->2->3->1->2->3

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild the Fedora `wmctrl` SRPM to work on RHEL.

First, [download the SRPM](http://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/wmctrl/1.07/8.fc15/src/wmctrl-1.07-8.fc15.src.rpm).  Then, run this command as `root` to obtain all build dependencies:

```
yum-builddep wmctrl-1.07-8.fc15.src.rpm
```

Then, run this command (as a normal user, ***not*** `root`) to rebuild the RPM:

```
rpmbuild --rebuild wmctrl-1.07-8.fc15.src.rpm
```

That will drop an RPM file in `~/rpmbuild/RPMS/<arch>` you can install as you normally would (through PackageKit or `rpm -ivh`).